# Cant seem to make correct xpath or identify certain websites elements

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

!. For the most part I can write xpath but on some websites the element will be in like an iframe or something and I seriously can't figure out how to make it's xpath.  The website is https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en and i cant seem to get the xpath for the choose username field.  I've tried many times to get it to work but I can't with anything.  I've tried iframe input also I've tried using cssSelectors find by id. Everything. Please help

2. Also, how would one make an xpath for a button that occurs multiple times on a site.  What I mean is say your in like a youtube comment section and there's tons of comments.  I want to somehow identify the like button on one of the comments but whenever I go into inspect element it seems like they all share the same element.

Comment: What i mean by they all share the same element is i mean all the liikes buttons on the page seem to point to the same element.  Sorry if my terminology isn't correct i dont know anything about html and web development